# using mpl::fold with a placeholder and my own struct mishap

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I have the following primary template:

```
template<size_t pos, size_t lev>
struct Sol;
```

and I specialize it for some pos values like so:

```
template<size_t lev>
struct Sol<0, lev>
{
    static const mpl::vector_c<size_t, 4, 6> jumps;
    static const size_t value =
        mpl::fold<jumps, mpl::integral_c<size_t, 0>, 
                  mpl::plus<Sol<_1, lev-1>::value, 
                            Sol<_2, lev-1>::value> >::type::value;
}
```

but I get that `Sol` expected `size_t`  and got `mpl_::_1`. I know in this case I could probably omit this fold thing im trying to do and just declare value to be the sum of the one level lower values of the other two `Sol` structs for `pos` of 4 and 6..but I was wondering if this could be repaired in case the `vector_c` was a bit long to type out?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will do what you want. I've made a few changes.

First, I wrapped the `pos` **non-type template parameter** with a `mpl::integral_c`. In general, when using Boost.MPL, it is advised to wrap all your non-type template parameters. This way, you never have to distinguish them later on.

Second, I used **template metafunction forwarding**. What this means is that instead of defining a template data member `value` inside `Sol`, I simply derive `Sol` from a Boost.MPL template that contains that value. This will save you typing `::type::value` all over the place. Use good indentation to make the code easier to read.

Third, I wrapped your call to `mpl::plus` inside `mpl::fold` with a `boost::mpl::lambda`. This is not stricly necessary for the code you gave, but it will be if you use `Sol` itself inside another `mpl::fold` expression with other placeholder arguments (the lambda wrapping will delay evaluation until the entire template has been parsed).

Fourth, I made a full specialization to stop the recursion on your `lev` parameter. BTW, if you ever start doing compile-time computation ons `lev`, the same advise applies: wrap it first into a `mpl::integral_c`.

```
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/integral_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using namespace mpl::placeholders;

// primary template
template<typename pos, size_t lev>
struct Sol;

// partial specialization for zero position
template<size_t lev>
struct Sol< mpl::integral_c<size_t, 0>, lev>
:
        mpl::fold<
                mpl::vector_c<size_t, 4, 6>, 
                mpl::integral_c<size_t, 0>,
                mpl::lambda<
                        mpl::plus<
                                Sol<_1, lev-1>, 
                                Sol<_2, lev-1>
                        > 
                > 
        >        
{};

// full specialization for zero position and level
template<>
struct Sol< boost::mpl::integral_c<size_t, 0>, 0>
:
        boost::mpl::integral_c<size_t, 0> // or whatever else you need
{};
```

Comment: Thank you this is really cool! I'm a bit confused on the lambda though...how come in this case it is not 'strictly necessary'? I think mpl::apply internally uses lambda to convert the placeholder stuff into a metafunction class..does fold do the same? I see the metaforwarding trick at work, very nice too!

Comment: @PalaceChan The problems appear if you do a `mpl::fold` on `Sol<_1, lev>`, because then the `_1` inside the outer `mpl::fold` might get confused with the `_1` in the inner fold. If you use `Sol` as a standalone object, then there's no problem, but in general it is safer to wrap placeholders. There was a long thread on the boost mailinglist.  http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/01/189764.php